# How far could you see in air?

Tags: vision

Suppose a world that is infinitely large and flat, with an atmospheric composition and density similar to earth, how far could you see before the scattering effect of the air causes anything more distant to effectively fade out?

That is, ignoring the curvature of the earth and other obstructions like clouds or nearby mountains, and assuming you're observing something large enough that the angular size is big enough for your eye to pick out, what would the maximum surface-to-surface sight distance be?

Comment: Google  "Atmospheric extinction coefficient"

Answer (score 2):

How far can the human eye see in the air?
It also depends on the amount of dust and pollution in the air, which usually limits normal vision to less than 12 miles. However, in 1941 a vision scientist, Selig Hecht, worked out that, with a clear, unobstructed view, the human eye could see a candle light flickering about 30 miles away.

https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2014/may/10/ask-grown-up-how-far-can-our-eyes-see